# How do I populate an Android spinner using a JSON web service?

Tags: android, arrays, json, spinner

How do I parse a JSON file like the one below containing school names and IDs and use the values in the "Name" field to populate the spinner lables?

I want the spinner to output the selected SchoolID to the next activity. E.g. So you see "Hill View Elementary" and if you select this the value "HVE" is output to the next activity to act on.

```
{
"schools": [
{
"Name": "Hill View Elementary",
"SchoolID": "HVE"},
{
"Name": "Mill View",
"SchoolID": "MVE"},
{
"Name": "Big School",
"SchoolID": "BSC"},
]
}
```

Here is the onCreate I'm using to attempt to read the feed...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    String readFeed = readFeed();
    try {
      JSONArray jsonArray = new
      JSONArray(readFeed);
      Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(),
          "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());

      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        // Here instead of Logging I want to use each schools "Name" to 
        // be put into an array that I can use to populate the strings 
        // for the spinner

        Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("schools"));

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm still coming up to speed on Android so clarity appreciated.

Here is readfeed:

```
public String readFeed() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // domain intentionally obfuscated for security reasons
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.domain.com/schools.php");
    try 
 {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String
 line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
        }
      } else {
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
 {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public class School {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

On create:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    String readFeed = readFeed();

    // you can use this array to find the school ID based on name
    ArrayList<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();
    // you can use this array to populate your spinner
    ArrayList<String> schoolNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readFeed);
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json.optString("schools"));
      Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(),
          "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());

      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        School school = new School();
        school.setName(jsonObject.optString("Name"));
        school.setId(jsonObject.optString("SchoolID"));
        schools.add(school);
        schoolNames.add(jsonObject.optString("Name"));

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, schoolNames));
}
```

In your main_activity.xml you need a `Spinner`. The code above would work with a Spinner named like below:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Looks good but I'm getting the error "The method optValue(String) is undefined for the type jsonObject". (I'm compiling for 2.3.3).

Comment: sorry it should be `optString()`.  Try now.

Comment: That helps. And in the activity_main.xml should I state:
    android:entries="@array/schools"
(how do I get the spinner to use the populated array?)

Comment: OK this compiles (great stuff!). But my spinner is still empty. So either my feed is incorrect (works for an equivalent iPhone app and passes JSONlint) or my readFeed is not working. 

Is there a way of checking my feed is being ingested correctly into jsonArray? (A tip off is that I'm not seeing 'Number of entries' appearing in LogCat).

Comment: you could be catching an exception.  can you debug and step through it?

Comment: Okay try now.  You needed to actually get the "schools" array out of the json.

Comment: The first school name now appears in the spinner, but not all 3. Any ideas?

Comment: readfeed() now posted to body of conversation. Let me know if you need the true URL of the feed (prefer to send you privately / not post to this board).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18115/discussion-between-rihallix-and-james-m)

Comment: can you tell me how to get the schoolID associated with the school name after user selects a name???