# FIll Spinner from xml response in android

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I have response from webservice in that form.

```
[{"text":"1001","val":"1"},{"text":"2005","val":"2"},{"text":"2791","val":"3"}]
```

I want to load this in spinner android kindly guide me i am newbie in development.

Comment: You have to parse this response before showing it in the spinner.

Comment: You need to add only the text or with value?

Comment: I need to show text and on the bases of selected text. and store value in db.

Comment: If you like any answer, please accept it and close the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of custom bean class after parsing this json data.
Then you can write an adapter using this custom bean type list and can set the adapter on spinner.

For example,

```
String jsonData= [{"text":"1001","val":"1"},{"text":"2005","val":"2"},{"text":"2791","val":"3"}];
```

Our bean class is

```
class DataModel{
     private String text, value;
    // create Getter setters for the strings
}
```

Then parse the data and create an arraylist of type `DataModel`.

```
ArrayList<DataModel>= new ArrayList();
```

Next is create an custom adapter  and then set the adapter on the spinner.
That's it.

Comment: this is not valid answer.Please post your code with custom bean and custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The data format is `JSON`.

What you have to do is as follows :

1. Use `AsyncTask` for retrieving data from web-service.
2. Parse the `Json` received from web-service.
3. Now when it's parsed you have to use parsed data to be populated into the spinner using custom spinner adapter.

Here is [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/) for the same and a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906681/how-do-i-populate-an-android-spinner-using-a-json-web-service) post.